# Find out expected value of $\xi^2\eta^2$

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

The task: Find out expected value of $\xi^2\eta^2$, where $(\xi,\eta)$ has normal distribution with zero mean vector and covariance matrix
$(\begin{matrix}
4 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{matrix})$

I tryed to find the expected value with new random value as ($\eta- c\xi$), where c=const and cov($\xi, \eta- c\xi$)=0, but it only complicates the calculations.

Comment: You might prefer to look at $(\xi-\eta,\eta)$ which I suspect has a very simple covariance matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another is to write $X=\sqrt 3 Z + Y$ where $Z$ is independent of $Y$  and has the same distribution as $Y$  and has $EZ=0$ and $V(Z)=1$ (that is, $N(0,1)$). 
Check: $V(X) = 3V(Z)+V(Y) = 3 + 1 = 4$, and $\text{Cov}(X,Y)= \text{Cov}(Y,Y) =1$.  Then $X^2Y^2 = 3Z^2Y^2+2\sqrt 3 ZY^3 + Y^4$, whose expectation is $EZ^2EY^2+2\sqrt3 EZEY^3+EY^4=3+0+3=6$.  (The 4th moment of $Y$ is $3$; see the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments).)

Comment: Z is a random value? And how we get the coefficient $\sqrt{3}$? And the last question- why $EY^4=3$?

Comment: I have addressed these issues in an edit.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation):

$$E(X^2Y^2)=E\left[E(X^2Y^2\mid Y)\right]=E\left[Y^2E(X^2\mid Y)\right]$$

Here $(X,Y)$ is jointly normal, so that $X\mid Y$ is  univariate normal from which you can find $$E(X^2\mid Y)=V(X\mid Y)+(E(X\mid Y))^2$$

Comment: What is X | Y ?

Comment: @Matthew5335 The random variable $X$ conditioned on the random variable $Y$ ('X given Y').

Comment: V(...) is Variance? And how is it possible to calculate $E(X | Y)$?

Comment: 'V' is variance. And looks like you are not yet acquainted with this theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case_2https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case_2.